# How to implement the function bootstrp to obtain a plot of the power regarding the number of observations of a statistical test

Tags: matlab, statistics-bootstrap

I am doing experiments on human subjects where they have to perform a piloting task. Their performance is rated by measuring the distance between their trajectory and the center of targets in the sky. I have 8 subjects for the test condition and 8 subjects for the control condition. My data are non-parametric and independent. I am analyzing the statistical difference with a Wilcoxon Rank Sum test in Matlab (ranksum).

However, I would like to know what is the power of my test and how many subjects I would need to have a given power. As my data don’t follow a normal distribution (non-parametric), I cannot use the Matlab function sampsizepwr.

I found in some studies that we could do a bootstrap analysis to obtain a plot of the power regarding to the number of subjects. Matlab has the function bootstrap but I don't understand how to implement it. Does anyone know how to use bootstrap with Matlab to compute the power as a function of the sample size for non-parametric and independent data?

Thank you for your help!

Carine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have 2 samples `g1`, `g2`, you would run:

```
p = ranksum(g1,g2)
N = 100;
bootstat = bootstrp(N,@ranksum,g1,g2);
```

Where `N` is the number of sampling tries. `bootstat` is a list of the `ranksum` statistic p-value for all `N` samples. The power of the test is the probability that your test reject H<sub>0</sub> in those samples:

```
pow = sum(bootstat<alpha)/N
```

where `alpha` is the significance level (typically 5%).

---

**Edit:**

To make things more specific, I simulate some data that have  similar properties as yours:

```
smpsz = [4 8 20 200]; % sample size
for n = 1:numel(smpsz)
    g1 = rand(1,smpsz(n)).*repelem([3.36 6.72],smpsz(n)/2)+repelem([0 3.36],smpsz(n)/2);
    g2 = rand(1,smpsz(n)).*repelem([8.13 8.13*2],smpsz(n)/2)+repelem([0 8.13],smpsz(n)/2);
    N = [5 10 50 100 500]; % no. of tries
    for k = 1:numel(N)
        bootstat2 = bootstrp(N(k),@ranksum,g2,g1);
        bootstat1 = bootstrp(N(k),@ranksum,g1,g2);
        pow(1,k) = sum(bootstat1<0.05)/N(k);
        pow(2,k) = sum(bootstat2<0.05)/N(k);
    end
    disp(smpsz(n))
    disp(pow)
end
```

The result:

```
 4
      0.2          0.2         0.02         0.05        0.058
        0          0.2         0.06         0.05        0.072
 8
      0.6          0.3          0.7         0.66        0.552
      0.6          0.5         0.56         0.58          0.6
20
        1          0.8          0.9         0.86        0.908
        1          0.7         0.86         0.88        0.898
200
 1     1     1     1     1
 1     1     1     1     1
```

you can see above that `pow` does not get better (higher) along the rows, i.e. with a greater `N`, and also here is no significant difference between every two adjacent rows, i.e. the order of groups does not matter. However, it does increase as sample size (`smpsz`) increases from 4 to 200.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help !
I implemented your code and tested it with my data. However, the power doesn’t increase when I increase the number of N (even if I take N=200). Is it because my data have a too big variation between my subjects? 
I have for g1: median= 3.36, 25 percentile = 2.92 and 75 percentile = 4.99 and for g2: median= 8.13, 25 percentile = 5.53 and 75 percentile = 12.09 (results for N=8 subjects).
 In addition I don’t obtain the same result if I test bootstrp(N,@ranksum,g1,g2) or bootstrp(N,@ranksum,g2,g1). Do you know what could be the reason?

Comment: @Carine a greater `N` will give you a more **accurate**  result, but not more statistical power. Increasing the sample size does give higher power. See my edit to the answer for more details.

Comment: Thank you EBH for your reply. I had a confusion between sample size and number of tries but now it is all clear. Do you know if there is a way to estimate the power as a function of the sample size? In my case I have a fixed sample size defined by the number of experiments I ran. I am interested to know how much more experiments I should run to reach a given power. My data are non-parametric and independent. I am analyzing the statistical difference with a Wilcoxon Rank Sum test in Matlab (ranksum). Thank you for your help, Carine

Comment: @Carine I'm glad it helps you. Please consider accepting this answer to follow the [site guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). As for your second question, it is more statistics than programming, so you better look in [stats.se]. Here is [one answer from there](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37796/calculating-necessary-sample-size-using-bootstrap)